# Why SpringBoot validation not work with single @PropertySource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-validation

My Source code:

Person.java

```java
@Component
@Validated
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:person.yaml")

@Data
public class Person {
    @NotNull(message = "test can't be null")
    private String test;
    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;
    @Autowired
    private Cat pet;
    @Max(value=120,message="invalid age")
    @Value("${age}")
    private int age;

    @Email(message = "invalid email address")
    @Value("${email}")
    private String email;
}
```

person.yaml

```yaml
name: "test"
email: "abcdefg"
age: 11111
```

I use my Person class on SpringBootApplication with invalid email address and age, but it ran successfully without any validation exception.

[image: imagef8e160a66fd93d78.png]

But If I replace the `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:person.yaml")` to `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "person")` or use both `@PropertySource` and `@ConfigurationProperties`

application.yaml

```yaml
person:
  name: "test"
  email: "abcdefg"
  age: 11111
```

My SpringBoot throw an validation exception successfully.
[image: image.png]

Answer (score 0):

From `@PropertySource` documantation:

> Annotation providing a convenient and declarative mechanism for adding a PropertySource to Spring's Environment. To be used in conjunction with @Configuration classes.

You don't have `@Configuration` anotation under class declaration.

Your second example has @ConfigurationProperties annotation and this is from documentation:

> Annotation for externalized configuration. Add this to a class definition or a @Bean method in a @Configuration class if you want to bind and validate some external Properties (e.g. from a .properties file).

In a nutshell: `@PropertySource` need `@Configuration` but `@ConfigurationProperties` not.

**EDIT:**
Last not first visible detail: PropertySource cannot read yaml files :-)

Comment: But why I added the `@Configuration` to my Person class which used `@PropertySource`, It still didn't work.

Comment: For using PropertySource you must use *.properties configuration file. PropertySource doesn't read yamls.